# Comparing dataframes to eachother based on a column only to return outliers that do not have a match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Creating an end of day reconciliation process to ensure there are no outliers at the end of the business day. This is a tad complex as I need to compare dataframes to and from each other, only to leave values that are not duplicates (aka outliers). I am trying to compare df1 to/from df2. Also trying to compare df1 to/from df3. All three dataframes have two columns: ID, Source. ID column is comprised of different features such as amount (negative or positive), 9-digit number and person. Examples of this with positive & negative amounts looks like this: 20_777666333_bob or -1000_932143097_john.

Example: If I am comparing df1 to/from df2. If df1 has a value in the ID column = 20_777666333_bob and df2 did not have a matching value in the ID column = 20_777666333_bob then I would expect the outlier to be returned as 20_777666333_bob in its own dataframe which i will later use to populate in an email.

Below is the current logic that I am struggling with. If anyone knows why its returning all duplicates and no outliers that would be extremely helpful. Also, if anyone has an idea to code this differently I am all ears. Thank you for your time.

```
# List of dataframes
dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]

# Iterate through dataframes and drop duplicates
for i, df in enumerate(dataframes, start=1):
    dataframes[i-1] = df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID')

# Display the updated dataframes
for i, df in enumerate(dataframes, start=1):
    print(f"DataFrame {i} after dropping duplicates:")
    print(df)
    print()
```

Updating post with better examples to help answer my question.

'''
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [20_777666333_bob, -1000_932143097_john, -5_987443211_jane], "Source": ["A"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [440_098742123_jim, 680_715355572_bill, 20_777666333_bob], "Source": ["B"]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [680_715355572_bill, -1000_932143097_john, -900_976165534_sean], "Source": ["C"]})

x = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep=False)

'''

I would expect my outlier dataframe (x) to have 3 outliers:

1. ID = -5_987443211_jane, Source A
2. ID = 440_098742123_jim, Source B
3. ID = -900_976165534_sean, Source C

Currently when I use the above logic I am still seeing outliers when I expect not to. Could it have to do with the datatype of ID column? When I concat them df1, df2, and df3 all turn to datatype = object for ID column, but before I concat them df1 = object, df2 = string and df3 = string.

Comment: if you need only values (not full rows) then you can convert to `set()` and use `set(one_list) ^ set(other_list)`. You may also use special dictionary `collection.Counter()` to count elements.  Eventually you could join/merge/concatenate `dataframes` into one `dataframe` and use (probably) `.value_count()` (or maybe `.count_values()` - I don't remeber) or use `drop_duplicates()`

Comment: it would be simpler if you would put example data directly in code - and show expected result.

Comment: df.drop_duplicates() will drop duplicate IDs within one dataframe. Also, as a rule of thumb you shouldn't modify what you're iterating over.

Comment: Perhaps `pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicate(subset='ID', keep=False)` (and the same for `[df1, df3]`)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that might work for you, that involves merging the dataframes and dropping the rows that merge properly.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,4,5], "Source": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,3,4,5], "Source": ["aa", "cc", "dd", "ee"]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,4,9], "Source": ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ii"]})

outliers_list = []
for curr_df in [df2, df3]:
  curr_outliers = df1.merge(curr_df, on="ID", how="outer", indicator=True)
  print(curr_outliers.head())
  curr_outliers = curr_outliers[curr_outliers._merge != "both"]
  curr_outliers.drop(columns=['_merge'], inplace=True)
  outliers_list.append(curr_outliers.copy())

outliers = pd.concat(outliers_list)
print(outliers.head())
```

Comment: i tried your solution and unfortunately it showed me everything instead of outliers, but I believe it has to do with you thinking the source column will have matching values. I want to ignore the source column when i attempt to drop all matches on ID column. For some reason when I switch "outer" to "inner" i receive no outliers which is expected for today. Do you think i need to use inner instead of outer?

Comment: I'm ignoring the "Source" column. If that isn't clear to you from my code, you should spend some time figuring out what exactly it's doing. That being said, how="outer" will give you what you call the "outliers". How="inner" will end up with an empty dataframe every time, because the line ```curr_outliers = curr_outliers[curr_outliers._merge != "both"]``` is dropping all the rows where the row's "ID" is in both dataframes.

Comment: If you comment out the lines ```curr_outliers = curr_outliers[curr_outliers._merge != "both"]``` and ```curr_outliers.drop(columns=['_merge'], inplace=True)```, and remove the ```indicator=True``` parameter from ```df1.merge()```, and change ```how``` to ```"inner"```, the code will give you only those IDs that occur in both dataframes.